# Javascript Modules Controls

Tags: javascript, module, return

I am currently working on modules but my confusion is that when I code `return` object in function it can called outside function scope, but when I code standard object like `var obj = {some: something}` then this can't be called outside the function scope. Why and how?

```js
// Return Object
var ray = (function(){
    return {
        speak: function (){
            console.log("Haseeb");
        }
    };
})();
ray.speak();

// Standard Object
var ray = (function(){
        var obj = {
           speak: function (){
            console.log("Haseeb");
        }         
    }
})();

obj.speak();
```

Comment: if you don't declare obj inside function then it will become window object .

Comment: what if i declare ray.obj ? similarly like top ray.speak

Comment: since you are returning nothing then ray would be undefined. better to remove `var` from object declaration .

Comment: you mean to say that if i return obj then it can be called outside the function scope ? but not like this ray.obj.speak ? it can called ray.speak or obj.speak why and how? still little bit confuse

Comment: you need to return `obj` in your second example.  and you can use ray.speak();

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming that you meant to write `ray.speak();` instead of `obj.speak();`;

```
// Standard Object
var ray = (function(){
  var obj = {
    speak: function (){
      console.log("Haseeb");
    }         
  }
})();
```

In this snippet, when anonymous function is executed it returns **nothing** back to `ray` variable, so when you try to access `speak()` method from `ray`, it throws an error saying `Cannot read property 'speak' of undefined`.

But in your first snippet, the anonymous function does return an object with `speak` method so you can call, `ray.speak()`.

Comment: yup helpful i understand

Answer (score 0):

```
// Standard Object
var ray = (function(){
        var obj = {
           speak: function (){
            console.log("Haseeb");
        }         
    }
})();

obj.speak();
```

This does not work because of how lexical scoping works. Obj on the outside has no context to what is defined inside of the function because the obj is declared inside the block scope of the function. If, however obj was declared in the same scope, it will work as expected.

```
 var obj;
 // Standard Object
var ray = (function(){
       obj = {
           speak: function (){
            console.log("Haseeb");
        }         
    }
})();

obj.speak();
```

`ray.speak()` will not work because it does not have a binding to obj.
`return obj={...}` will be a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding JavaScript variable scope would help:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Now coming to your code.
In the first snippet, the variable 'ray' gets assigned the value returned by the the self executed function, which is the object returned. It is similar to this:

```
var ray = {
        speak: function (){
            console.log("Haseeb");
        }
    };
```

So now the statement below is valid as 'ray' has a property 'speak'

```
ray.speak();
```

However, in the second part of the snippet, nothing is returned by the self executed function, so, it is similar to:

```
var ray = undefined;
```

Now the statement '`ray.speak()`' is same as executing '`undefined.speak()`', which would throw an error, obviously.

Also, executing `obj.speak` is same as executing '`undefined.speak()`', because the variable 'obj' is only available inside that self executing function. Outside the function, 'obj' is not defined.

Hope this helps. :)

**Edit:**

**Explanation for your question about the return statement:**

The return statement returns whatever is the output of the code/statement in front of it.

Examples:

```
var a = 2;
return a; // will return a's value, i.e. '2'

var obj = { x:1 };
return obj; // will return the obj variable's value i.e. { x:1 }

var a = 1;
return a > 1; // will return false i.e. what 'a > 1' outputs after execution
```

so if you write

```
return obj = { x:1 };
```

this will return what the assignment 'obj = { x:1 }' outputs, which is obj's assigned value.

Now coming to your code

```
var ray = (function(){
        return obj = {
           speak: function (){
            console.log("Haseeb");
        }         
    }
})();
```

Here the return statement doesn't make obj available to the scope outside the function, it just returns the value of obj, which is then assigned to 'ray'. 
The reason that you are able to do `obj.speak()` without getting any exceptions is that you have used the variable obj without declaring it inside the function using 'var' keyword, which results in 'obj' getting automatically declared in the global scope. And that is why you are able to access 'obj' outside of the function too.

If you change your code to this:

```
var ray = (function(){
    var obj;
    return obj = {
           speak: function (){
            console.log("Haseeb");
        }         
    }
})();
```

You will get exception while trying to execute `obj.speak()` outside the function. Because 'obj' is now declared and available only inside the function.

I would suggest reading some more tutorials about variable scope in JavaScript and playing around a bit on the console. :)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thats great simply helpful i understand about that :)

Comment: but there is a confusion that when i used return obj ={speak: function() { } } so it can work outside scope like this ray.speak which simply means that according to you var ray = {
speak: function(){
}, but one more thing its also can called obj.speak so how you can distinguish between ray.speak or obj.speak both they object of speak ?

Comment: and in many cases after written return obj ={} object i try to check on console.log few things in which somethings does not work like 

console.log(ray.speak());
console.log(obj.speak());
console.log(ray.obj);

Here is the snippet i written 

var ray = (function(){
         return obj = {
           speak: function (){
            return console.log("Haseeb");
        }         
    }
})();

Comment: I have edited the answer to include explanation for your confusion. Please accept the answer if you feel it clarified your doubts. :)